# Custom query on wordpress author page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am not expert on php and need some help about custom query on my wordpress author page.

I have no problem when using *WP_User_Query*, the problem is i need to combine it with *$curauth*

What i need to do is get authors list with *WP_User_Query* that filtered with current author page as a custom field value.

here is code that got error:

```
// WP_User_Query arguments
$curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));
$label = echo $curauth->user_login;
$args = array (
'role'           => 'contibutor',
'number'         => '10',
'order'          => 'ASC',
'orderby'        => 'display_name',
'meta_query'     => array(
    array(
        'key'       => 'user_label',
        'value'     => $label,
    ),
),
);

// The User Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

// The User Loop
if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
    // do something
}
} else {
// no users found
}
```

I hope someone here can help to resolve my problem. Thank you

Comment: Could you post the error message you got? It will help you get a faster response.

Comment: This is the error msg i got from the server log: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in` I don't know how is the syntax to echo the `$curauth->user_login;` on the query, thanks

Comment: Just remove the `echo` in ths line `$label = echo $curauth->user_login;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$curauth = ( isset( $_GET['author_name'] ) ) ? get_user_by( 'slug', $author_name ) : get_userdata( intval( $author ) );

$args = array (
    'role' => 'contibutor',
    'number' => '10',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'display_name',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'user_label',
            'value' => $curauth->user_login,
        ),
    ),
);

// The User Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

// The User Loop
if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
        // do something
    }
} else {
    // no users found
}
```

As pointed out by [pieter-goosen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1908141/pieter-goosen) in the comments, the line `$label = echo $curauth->user_login;` was causing the error message.